# Is it okay to ask mathematical puzzles and problems I have solved?

Tags: discussion

I went through [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/are-please-check-my-proof-type-of-questions-proper) but it doesn't answer my question entirely. My question is a little different.

I want to post a problem I've already solved for the sole purpose of watching how others solve it or what insights or techniques other people may provide. After posting the question, I would like to post my solution as an answer, so that my solution is open to voting as well. This way I can know what the community feels about my solution. I can find out whose solution is the most elegant one as per the community.

In other words, I want to post a question not to ask for help but to have fun and to learn from others. Is this a good thing to do in math.se?

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/is-math-puzzle-on-topic-or-off-topic

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. This is [explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) by the Powers That Be.

Comment: What would be the right way to indicate that this is a puzzle for fun purpose? Because I would want people to participate in that question in the spirit of coming up with elegant solutions rather than trying to teach me how to solve it.

Comment: What if you were to say exactly that when you posted the question?

Comment: Thanks @MarkDominus. It makes sense. I was wondering if there is some tag that I can use to tag my questions. This would help me to avoid explaining the same thing every time I post such a question.

Comment: @Lon: not really. Why would it be difficult for you to indicate in the body that you want other solutions?

Comment: @LoneLearner There is (recreational-mathematics) tag, but I think that it would be nice to have explicit notification in the question body.