# What to do when I get no feedback on an answer to my own question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, hint

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294375/what-properties-of-this-complex-function-can-be-deduced) sometime ago and had no idea how to solve it. Later, I got a hint(the first answer there) and used it to reach a conclusion, which I then wrote in the comments. The person who gave the hint confirmed the answer was correct and I let the matter be. Sometime later, I remembered it, out of nowhere, and realized that my reasoning could have been wrong. So, I posted an answer and thought somebody would tell me whether it is correct(possibly the original hint-giver). But, I got none. What do I do in such circumstances when I want my reasoning(not more than 3-4 steps) glanced at, by an expert?

Comment: Perhaps the title should be edited to reflect the immediate concern you have.  Although you begin in the body by describing a "hint" you got in an answer to the Question, by the end the focus seems to be on having posted a self-answer that you are unsure about.  "But, I got none" of the expected feedback, you write.  If you like I can try to edit the title for you.

Comment: please do. I am not sure the title is relevant either

Comment: This seems to be similar to this older post: [How to bring an answer to attention?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13198) You can also have a look at [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3478) and [other posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3478).

Comment: It could be that you're actually completely correct. Sometimes you can be wrong on a small detail and they won't let you hear the end of it.

Comment: @Truth-seek for what it's worth, I had no way of knowing that you posted an answer to that question since I don't exactly check my old answers regularly.  If you wanted my attention, you could have put a comment under my answer, or pinged me under your answer.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't think pinging under their answer would have worked. Ordinary users can only ping somebody who commented on or edited the same post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answerers don't get notified when other answers are posted. If you didn't post a comment below the hint saying that you'd posted a self-answer, the person who wrote the hint will not know you did that.

However, this isn't really what Stack Exchange is for. The expectation is that answers are believed to be correct by the person who posted them. Answers are taken as meaning, "To the best of my ability, this is the solution to the problem at the top of the page" not "Could you please tell me if this is right?" The latter is a question, not an answer.

Answer (score 7):

You should probably ask a question.

You know, of course, that there are two main ways to contribute to any Stack Exchange site: asking questions and posting answers. When people ask questions, they are *seeking* knowledge from others, and when people answer questions, they are *offering* knowledge. The entire design of the site is made to facilitate that flow of information from answerers to askers, but it doesn't work quite so well going in an opposite direction. So if you want feedback on something, it's best if you do so in the form of a question, even if the thing you are asking about happens to be an answer to another question.

If your question wouldn't be appropriate on the site, you could try bringing it up in chat.