# Should answering that someone's attempt is correct be posted as a comment?

Tags: discussion, comment, answers, flagging, solution-verification

In my opinion, if someone's attempt at a problem is correct then confirming this should be done as commentary. Obviously if the attempt is flawed, saying what is wrong/hinting at the correct path can be posted as an answer.

The definition of 'Answer' is 'a correct response to a question', and replying 'your solution is correct' is clearly correct. However, when I see such answers I always feel the need to flag them for 'not an answer - it should possibly be a comment' but every time I refrain myself from doing so. Should I raise the flag or let it be as it is?

Comment: This seems related: [How to answer proof-verification questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20097)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As detailed elsewhere (see [How to answer proof-verification questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20097/how-to-answer-proof-verification-questions)) I do not consider it as best practice to post *only* "this is correct" as an answer. Usually, something more can be said to make for an actual post (see the above mentioned post).

Dually, I agree with the view expressed on [Best way of asking "check my proof" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/best-way-of-asking-check-my-proof-questions), that usually *only* asking "is this correct" is not a best practice, but instead a particular concern should be formulated. If somebody cannot articulate any reason why they think their solution might be incorrect, there is not really a case for asking to begin with. (This concern can be vague and fuzzy, but still some reason ought to exist.)

As a combination of the above two I think that to comment: "This is correct. Why did you think it might be incorrect?" can sometimes be a good approach to get to a more meaning full Q&A pair.

Coming back to the specific question asked, I think it is a judgment call. But in certain cases, in particular early on in the history of a post, I do think it can be justified to turn n answer that only says "This is correct." into a comment, and you can flag in that sense. Yet, I would advise against doing this in old cases where already everything is resolved, with accepted answer etc.