# What is an appropriate format to ask help for a specific problems in a given book

Tags: discussion

I will do my best and try to self study Diestel's Graph Theory during the next few years. This will obviously result me asking help/proof checking in this forum, so I would like to be on the same page with everyone else in terms of the format used for, say proof checking. Is a format of "Seeking proof checking for {Bookname} {problem number/title} considered appropriate? I do not think I have the same "misconfusion" when asking help for finishing up problems, as you usually know what you do not understand (and can use that as the title).

Comment: Since you mention "proof checking", you may also like to read [Best way of asking “check my proof” questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4597/780640)

Comment: A title which only contains "{Bookname} {problem number/title}" is only useful for other people searching for answers to that specific problem from that specific book; it will attract fewer people to answer the question than a more descriptive answer, and it ignores the fact that the same question may occur in many different texts (although please do include the reference in the body of the text).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would recommend that you describe the mathematical content of your question in a self-contained way in the title - bibliographic information is certainly important and useful to some (and absolutely should be included in the body of the question for context), but it's not as broadly accessible as a brief description of the mathematical content; I would suggest that a title like:

> Is this proof that every tree has a leaf correct? (Diestel's Graph Theory Exercise 2.15)

would be good - the title is easy for other people to come across either by searching for a particular question from the book or by searching for the general graph theoretic terms (possibly coming from other sources). This also allows answerers to see the content of the question immediately and to determine easily whether it's relevant to them. In case this title would be too long, you would be better off just using "Is this proof that every tree has a leaf correct?" and putting the source in the body of the post.

Answer (score 7):

That title would be OK. Better: put the problem number in the body, use the title to provide information about the theorem being proved.