# What to do with a "check/simplify my proof" type question?

Tags: discussion, closing, unanswered-questions, solution-verification

After doing reading on the meta I have come to realise that asking for a verification of a proof is not necessarily a good idea. Among other reasons, it has a fair chance to be left without an answer. I have come across some very helpful suggestions [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/are-please-check-my-proof-type-of-questions-proper) and [there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/best-way-of-asking-check-my-proof-questions).

I have, however, made mistakes in my youth, and asked questions about whether or not a reasoning is correct, and if there is a simpler one, such as the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115679/integral-of-laplacian-of-a-positive-function). I think I am not the only one here to have erred in this way, and contributed to the 9,065 currently existing unanswered questions.

My question is, what should one do with a "check my proof" or "is there a simpler proof" type of question to close it? Two things that come to mind are:

1. Post a short CW answer saying that apparently no errors nor simplifications were found, and the question ought to be closed. Next, accept it as the answer.
2. Vote for closing the question on the grounds of not really being a question at all. (Possibly too strong, since I am under the impression that closing is reserved for really bad questions).

Comment: Well done. I would upvote the answer (without upvotes the question is still considered Unanswered) but I'm out of votes now. Maybe someone else will.

Comment: @LVK: Thank you. Will it still be considered Unanswered if it is accepted? I find that surprising.

Comment: Not sure, but you are probably right, accepted would not be Unanswered anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree with Qiaochu. I would leave a comment asking what part of the proof is proving troublesome. If the proof is okay, a CW response to that effect seems proper. If there is significant correction necessary, that would probably warrant some helpful suggestions.