# Can I ask questions about reasoning?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are “please check my proof” type of questions proper?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/are-please-check-my-proof-type-of-questions-proper)

For instance, I'm studying the properties of a relation, I have to determine if R being a relation is antisymmetric or not, writing down my reasoning. I would like to ask if my reasoning is correct and know the reasons why I'm wrong. Is it possible in math.stackexchange? If not, what do you recommend?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/are-please-check-my-proof-type-of-questions-proper. Also related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6636/would-a-tag-for-check-my-proof-questions-be-useful/6641#6641

Comment: Short answer: Yes.